# JSON.stringify sum numbers automaticlly

Tags: node.js, json, stringify

I got a text file with a list of text which represents different box sizes:

```
3x11x24
13x5x19
1x9x27
24x8x21
6x8x17
etc...
```

Using node.js, I'm trying to put those inside an object.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const quetion = () => {
    fs.readFile('./list.txt', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', err)
        }
    const rawData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    const rawList = rawData.data;
    console.log(rawList)
    })
}

quetion();
```

Now, as I console.log(rawData) to CLI, I get this object:

```
[
   51, 120,  49,  49, 120, 50,  52,  13,  10,  49, 51, 120,
   53, 120,  49,  57,  13, 10,  49, 120,  57, 120, 50,  55,
   13,  10,  50,  52, 120, 56, 120,  50,  49,  13, 10,  54,
  120,  56, 120,  49,  55, 13,  10,  49,  57, 120, 49,  56,
  120,  50,  50,  13,  10, 49,  48, 120,  57, 120, 49,  50,
   13,  10,  49,  50, 120, 50, 120,  53,  13,  10, 50,  54,
  120,  54, 120,  49,  49, 13,  10,  57, 120,  50, 51, 120,
   49,  53,  13,  10,  49, 50, 120,  56, 120,  49, 55,  13,
   10,  49,  51, 120,
  ... 9010 more items
]
```

Those are the **sums** that has been automaticlly calculated from the numbers equations, and that is done  by JSON.stringify.
How do I prevent JSON.stringify from doing those calculations by default, to I can have the equations as simple strings inside the object?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Replace this
const rawData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
const rawList = rawData.data;
console.log(rawList)

//With this
const list = data.toString().split("\n").filter(e=>e);
console.log(list)
```

## Eplanation

You don't need to do any json operations on the file contents since it is not in json format.

What you do need to do with it is

1. Convert the Buffer to String via `.toString()`
2. Split it at newline `\n` to make an array
3. `.filter` out empty lines (in case there's any)

Comment: I get for this - SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 1

Comment: What does your file look like?

Comment: It's a txt file that I copied this [input](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/2/input) and paste it there.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood what you were trying to do

Comment: I thought you were trying to parse json

Comment: Edited my answer